# Mysterious gap between divs in image slider

Tags: html, css

I built a quick jQuery image slider today, but there's one problem. The images, which are inside divs, have a gap between them, offsetting them.

I've isolated the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/UgzsH/

`float: left;` gets rid of that gap, but apparently because of the elements they are in, they stack vertically.

Unfortunately from this computer I can only test in Firefox. Thanks for any help.

Test case uses http://placekitten.com/.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your HTML you have spaces between the divs and such. Try putting all the images and divs in one line of your HTML without spaces between the tags. No spaces!

Hope this helps and good luck!

EDIT: Here's the [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/UgzsH/15/). It looks a bit messy, but there are no spaces any more!

Comment: Thanks, I had never run into this problem before. But removing the whitespace would make the code harder to work with, especially if I want to use HTML on the slides rather than just images. Adding a line of code to remove the whitespace when the slider initiates works: http://jsfiddle.net/UgzsH/20/ Using `<pre>` or `<textarea>` might cause a problem, though.

Comment: No problem! Good luck on your site, if that is yours. Placekitten actually seems ridiculously awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Floating is how you get rid of the gap, but the last floated element is dropping down because the container is too small. The reason you get the gap is because elements that are `display: inline` with each other preserve the whitespace you get from the markup itself - if you remove the whitespace (meaning line-breaks) you'll notice the gaps go away. This makes your markup uglier, or course, hence why you use float instead. Make your containing div wider and they'll fit.

Comment: Thanks, but since this is an image slider, the other images need to be hidden horizontally, thus the containing div needs to be a set width.

Comment: You could also just set a height on your container then. The overflow:hidden would hide the image that dropped down. Setting the height to 100px, for example.

Comment: Then the images wouldn't slide horizontally, but vertically. Which is acceptable if that's what you're looking for, but usually that's not the case.

Comment: You could also hide the last image with another div: http://jsfiddle.net/UgzsH/22/ This sets relative position on the containing div, then makes another "screen" to position over the last picture. It seems a little hacky, but it works I guess.

Comment: Well, then the slider is too large. Unless you put it behind everything else on the page, placing the page into the 'screen' div, which is a bit unreasonable.

Comment: so you wanted to overflow the div but not have it affect anything else on the page? If you want to have 400px width of images, but not actually take up 400px, you're going to have to use positioning to take elements out of the flow anyway.